# javax.servlet.ServletException: bean [name] not found within scope

Tags: java, jsp, usebean

I'm getting this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: bean not found within scope
```

on a page with this at the top.

```html
<jsp:useBean id="bean" type="com.example.Bean" scope="request" />
```

The class exists in the classpath, it worked this morning, and I don't get what not found within scope means.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need the `class` attribute instead of the `type` attribute.

The following:

```html
<jsp:useBean id="bean" type="com.example.Bean" scope="request" />
```

does *basically* the following behind the scenes:

```java
Bean bean = (Bean) pageContext.getAttribute("bean", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);

if (bean == null) {
    throw new ServletException("bean not found within scope");
}

// Use bean ...
```

While the following:

```html
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="com.example.Bean" scope="request" />
```

does basically the following behind the scenes:

```java
Bean bean = (Bean) pageContext.getAttribute("bean", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);

if (bean == null) {
    bean = new Bean();
    pageContext.setAttribute("bean", bean, PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
}

// Use bean ...
```

If it has worked before and it didn't work "in a sudden", then it means that *something* which is responsible for putting the bean in the scope has stopped working. For example a servlet which does the following in the `doGet()`:

```java
request.setAttribute("bean", new Bean());
request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Maybe you've invoked the JSP page directly by URL instead of invoking the Servlet by URL. If you'd like to disable direct access to JSP pages, then put them in `/WEB-INF` and forward to it instead.

Comment: Although its too late,, but indeed a great explanation @BalusC

Answer (score 1):

You must add

```
<jsp:useBean id="givingFormBean" type="some.packg.GivingForm" scope="request" />
```

Because by default the bean is [looked on the *page* scope](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm14.html)