# Failed to make error handler using usebean

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to check if the dropdown list has no value with this code?

```
<td width="168"><select name="OrgType" class="txtbox" tabindex="1">
                            <option value="1">Please choose...</option>
                            <%
                                Iterator it2 = Org_Items2.iterator();
                                while (it2.hasNext())
                                {
                                    OrganizationItems orgItem2 = (OrganizationItems) it2.next();
                                    //EMSItems newsItem4 = new EMSItems();
                            %>
                            <option value=<%=orgItem2.getOrgTypeId()%>><%=orgItem2.getOrgTypeName()%></option>
                            <%
                                }
                            %>

                    </select></td>
                    <td width="120">
                        <%
                            if (errors.containsKey("OrgType"))
                            {
                                out.println("<span class=\"warning\">" + errors.get("OrgType") + "</span>");
                            }
                        %>
                    </td>
```

Then validation code

```
long OrgType = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("OrgType"));
    if ("1".equals(OrgType))
    {
        errors.put("OrgType", "Required");
    }
    else if(req.getParameter("OrgType") != null && !"".equals(req.getParameter("OrgType")))
    {
        long OrgTypeId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("OrgType"));
        emsItem.setOrgTypeId(OrgTypeId);
    }
```

I am using in my header page the usebean tag

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@ page import="data_registration_items.OrganizationItems"%>
<jsp:useBean id="Org_Items2" scope="request" type="java.util.List" />
```

but when I tried to leave the value of the drop down list as "Please Select..." I got the error

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: bean Org_Items not found within scope
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.organization_002dregistry_jsp._jspService(organization_002dregistry_jsp.java:79)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    web_registration.OrganizationServlet.doPost(OrganizationServlet.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    web.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:55)
```

How can I correcltly verified if the dropdown list pass the correct value?

---

I tried to delete the usebean in the header. In my servlet I already have the

```
List<OrganizationItems> orgItems2 = new SetOrganizationType().OrgTypeList();
req.setAttribute("Org_Items2", orgItems2).
```

under my doGet method...

in my jsp page I put the same code and the error says

```
Org_Items2 cannot be resolved
```

In the Option 2 I tried also but an error occured

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: Please help me about this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.InstantiationException: bean Org_Items not found within scope

The `<jsp:useBean>` will throw this exception when you use the `type` attribute instead of the `class` attribute and the desired bean instance is **not** available in the specified scope.

So there are basically 2 solutions:

1. Put the bean in the desired scope beforehand, so that `<jsp:useBean>` can find it.

   ```
   request.setAttribute("Org_Items", Org_Items);
   ```

   But, actually, this way you don't need the whole `<jsp:useBean>` at all. It would just be available directly in EL by `${Org_Items}`.
2. Use the `class` attribute instead so that `<jsp:useBean>` will autocreate one if it is not found in the scope. You should only change the FQN to `java.util.ArrayList`, because `java.util.List` has as being an interface no default constructor.

   ```html
   <jsp:useBean id="Org_Items2" scope="request" class="java.util.ArrayList" />
   ```

#### See also:

- [javax.servlet.ServletException: bean [name] not found within scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270444/javax-servlet-servletexception-bean-name-not-found-within-scope)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem. This piece of code contains some poor practices ([using *scriptlets*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/), not respecting [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367), using `<jsp:useBean>`). I recommend to learn how to separate the concerns and look at [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). It also contains an example with validation and error handling.

Comment: I tried to delete the usebean in the header. In my servlet I already have the req.setAttribute("Org_Items2", orgItems2);

Comment: So you're using a `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList`? Change the `class` attribute to `java.util.LinkedList`.