# InstanciationException Java bean

Tags: java, jsp, session, javabeans, usebean

im trying to do my first practices in JSP. I need instanciate a Java Bean using standard actions. I have the next bean:

```
package bean;

public class Cotizacion implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // Some properties ...

    public Cotizacion(){
        // Nothing ...
    }
    // Accessors & toString ...
}
```

So, in my JSP:

```
<%@ page import="bean.Cotizacion" %>
<%@ page session="true" %>

// HTML
<jsp:useBean id="bean" type="bean.Cotizacion" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
```

When i load the page, an exception is catched:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InstantiationException: bean
>   bean not found within scope

Whats wrong with my code ?

EDIT: Sory, i found the solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270444/javax-servlet-servletexception-bean-name-not-found-within-scope), i need to use the "class" attribute instead "type" for first time.